# Using reductions of turing machines properly

Tags: turing-machines

I recently learned about reductions of Turing machines (here after TM), and here is a solution to a problem using reduction (showing L is undecidable, as defined bellow). I have given the reduction, correctness proof and my understanding of it. I'm fairly certain it is correct, but I have found multiple times that with problems in Theory of Computation it is easy to misunderstand things. So I would greatly appreciate anyone's feedback!. (If this question is not suitable here please let me know where I should post!)

Suppose I want to reduce Htm to L, where Htm = { M, w | M halts on w} and L = { M | M is a TM, and M halts on all inputs of length at most 2016}

I then then define

f = on input (w, M), where w is a string, and M a TM

1. Construct the following TM, X

   X =" on input y

   ```
   1. Simulate M on w

   2. if (the simulation accepts or rejects) accept
   ```
2. return X

Correctness is proved as follows:
if (w, M) is in Htm, then X is in L, since in line 2 of X it will accept all strings. if (w, M) is not in Htm, then X will simply sloop, and thus will never halt which implies X is not in L.

If I understood correctly, when performing a reduction, you essentially use the input, in this case (w, M) and then transform it. So in this case, X is define in such a way that if its simulation halts (i.e. it accepts or rejects) it will halt (by accepting) but if the simulation of M on w does not halt, then X will never reach line 2, so essentially it will not halt for any inputs. In particular, it will not halt on any inputs of length of at most 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by Andreas, the reduction the OP is asking about is a many-one reduction or a mapping reduction (Sipser)

A language/problem A is mapping-reducible to a language/problem B if a function $f$ exists such that,

$w \in A \iff f(w) \in B$

In your example:

$H_{tm}$ is $A,\;$ $L$ is $B$

To prove your reduction, you would have to show:

$<M, w> \;\in H_{tm} \iff f(<M, w>) \in L$

You have done that because you have shown:

$<M, w> \;\in H_{tm}$
$\Rightarrow M$ halts on $w$
$\Rightarrow f(<M, w>)$ accepts all inputs
$\Rightarrow f(<M, w>) \in L$

and that

$f(<M, w>) \in L$
$\Rightarrow M$ halts on $w$
$\Rightarrow <M,w> \;\in H_{tm}$

Comment: What you call a Turing reduction here is usually called a many-one reduction.  The usual meaning of "Turing reduction" allows the computation for $A$ to make numerous queries to the oracle for $B$, with the later queries being chosen in a way that may depend on the answers to the earlier ones.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Noted and corrected in the post. Thank you.